# problem with adding option element in javascript with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a problem in the innerHTML of my javascript code, I take the variable minute, and paste innerhtml, to add an option element to have the selection of the minutes, only that he is not adding the elements in my select

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cronômetro</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        body{
            background-color: rgb(219, 218, 210);
        }
        h2{
            color: darkcyan;
            font-size: 20pt;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        button{
            width: 130px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            background-color: rgb(47, 155, 155);
            font-size: 15pt;
        }
        button:hover{
            color: white;
        }
        button:active{
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Minutos</h2><br>
        <select id="minutos" name="minutos"></select><br><br>
        <h2>Segundos</h2><br>
        <select id="segundos" name="segundos"></select><br><br>
        <button onclick="comecar()">Começar</button>
        <div id="tela">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var minutos = document.getElementsById("minutos")
        var segundos = document.getElementsById("segundos")
        var mostrarNaTela = document.getElementById("tela")

        for(var i = 0; i <= 60; i++){
            minutos.innerHTML+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

what can I do for him to add the elements in the select

Answer (score 1):

You mispelled your getElementById. There are no getElementsByID

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cronômetro</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-align: center;
        }
        body{
            background-color: rgb(219, 218, 210);
        }
        h2{
            color: darkcyan;
            font-size: 20pt;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        button{
            width: 130px;
            height: 40px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            background-color: rgb(47, 155, 155);
            font-size: 15pt;
        }
        button:hover{
            color: white;
        }
        button:active{
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Minutos</h2><br>
        <select id="minutos" name="minutos"></select><br><br>
        <h2>Segundos</h2><br>
        <select id="segundos" name="segundos"></select><br><br>
        <button onclick="comecar()">Começar</button>
        <div id="tela">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var minutos = document.getElementById("minutos")
        var segundos = document.getElementById("segundos")
        var mostrarNaTela = document.getElementById("tela")

        for(var i = 0; i <= 60; i++){
            minutos.innerHTML+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
There was a typo it should be getElementById


var minutos = document.getElementById("minutos")
var segundos = document.getElementById("segundos")
var mostrarNaTela = document.getElementById("tela")

var options = "" 

       for(var i = 0; i <= 60; i++){
         options +=  '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
        }
        
  minutos.innerHTML = options
```

Comment: If you're going to use snippets, be sure to test the results .. yours has errors

Comment: Of course there will be errors. I am not including whole big document tree in the code block. It already helps questioner.

Comment: Right, so if your code isn't testable, it's pointless to use a snippet. Otherwise just use a regular code block. It's confusing.

Comment: Confusing who ?  It looks like you are the only one who is confused!

Comment: Confusing in that you're giving code to test with a button to show how it works, which errors out. But, this wasn't meant to be heavy criticism, just a note to improve an answer. I forgot the SO motto `don't fix users, fix code` - I edited it in the interest of quality and clarity.

Comment: Ok I changed it but I think "If you're going to use snippets, be sure to test the results .. yours has errors" is not a polite sentence enough. Please make sure to speak to users not like they are your employee.